# Rust chroot execute command

Tags: rust

Why this code does not work ?

```rust
use std::env;
use std::os::unix::fs::chroot ;
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;
            
            
fn main() { 
    chroot("/home/user/rootfs").unwrap(); 
    std::env::set_current_dir("/").unwrap(); 
    env::set_var("PATH", "/usr/bin");
    let output = Command::new("/usr/bin/ls")
        .arg("-l")
        .arg("-a")
        .arg("/")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .output()
        .expect("ls command failed to start"); 
    println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
}
```

I created custom rootfs with debootstrap command on ubuntu distro .
I check `ls` command with this :

```
sudo chroot /home/user/rootfs /bin/bash -c "ls -l /"
```

but result of code is :

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'ls command failed to start: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:17:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Are you sure `ls` is in `/usr/bin` in your chroot, and not e.g. in `/bin`?

Comment: For testing please use the same command in your command line check and in your code, i.e. fully qualified path `/usr/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`.